# SQL: Show events of the next 2 weekends

Tags: mysql, sql

i'm using this query to show the events for the next 14 days:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
events
WHERE
eventdate
BETWEEN DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 HOUR))
AND
DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)
ORDER BY
eventdate
ASC
```

It also shows "running" events from "yesterday" (only 5 hours to 5 a.m.).

How can i show the events from NOW incl. the next 2 weekends?

It should not just show "stupid" 14 days.

Example:

Monday: Show 14 days to include both weekends
Thursday: Show only 10 days to include both weekends

Thanks!

Comment: What about Saturday or Sunday?

Comment: @PM 77-1: There are events during the week too.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution:

```
...
WHERE
eventdate
BETWEEN
DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 HOUR))
AND
DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL -WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE)+6 DAY), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [code] 14-weekday(now())[/code] 
Weekday return 0 for monday and 3 for thursday. If you dont mind time you can use curdate function.

All date time functions are covered here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html